# NGINX Reverse Proxy for Hulu TV Streaming

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, hulu

I am trying to setup nginx on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS on my local network to configure it as a reverse proxy for all local client requests to `hulu.com` via a VPN interface on my router...

I am new to nginx and have the following configuration in my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/reverse-proxy.conf` configured:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hulu.com;

    location / {
        proxy_bind 192.168.1.4;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass https://www.hulu.com;

      }
}
```

Some other possibly relevant information, I have a DNS resolver on my firewall resolving `hulu.com` to the local interface on my Ubuntu server `192.168.1.3` and I would like to bind the outgoing traffic to the second interface `192.168.1.4` as this traffic will be directed over the VPN on my router. The Ubuntu server uses external DNS to resolve `hulu.com` correctly.

So ultimately all nginx needs to do is to accept the requests and bind them to the alternate interface and let them continue on their way... and obviously return them to the client.

Once I get this functionality sorted I would like to extend it to use the content caching capabilities too.

Any assistance on this would be sincerely appreciated!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are encountering?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me when i try to browse to the site, my browser just returns with
"This site can't be reached,
 
www.hulu.com refused to connect.

Search Google for Hulu

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"